# Is it a better or faster way to this?

Tags: html, css

Does this tag has an  attribute  to skip 16 lines, because i cant find any.

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<hr> <!-- Hr Skills -->
```

Comment: Why do you need to skip 16 lines?

Comment: @MarkyPython because i cant find a better way to go under a section in my code.

Comment: `hr{margin-top: 19.2em; }` /* 16 * 1.2 */

Comment: You might want to rethink your design if you need to use sloppy code like that.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi what "em" means ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: We expect you to at least know the basics of the things you are working with...

Comment: @RajenderJoshi it was actually 24 em thanks that helped me think outside the box..because i was like "i need to find a solution for the <br> " but sometimes you just have to notice the forest and not the tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [the CSS margin properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

```
some-selector {
    margin-bottom: 16em;
}
```